# How to add new text in welcome page in blank space by changing inno setup script?

Tags: inno-setup

on welcome screen of inno setup i want to add NEW_TEXT in blank area just below the line "click Next to continue, or Cancel to exit Setup"

But only able to add NEW_TEXT above the line "click Next to continue, or Cancel to exit Setup" by overriding the value on the `[Messages]` section:

```
[Messages]
WelcomeLabel2=This will install [name/ver] on your computer.%n%nIt is recommended that you close all other applications before continuing %n%n NEW_TEXT.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

can i add text in that blank area specified above by editing inno setup script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decrease the height of the `WelcomeLabel2` which is stretched to the bottom of the page and create your own static text control for instance:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[CustomMessages]
WelcomeLabel3=Hello world!

[Code]
var
  WelcomeLabel3: TNewStaticText;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // you can set e.g. the fixed height to the original WelcomeLabel2, or
  // you can set the WelcomeLabel2 to auto-size to the text content it's
  // showing; to set the fixed height, use the following line:
  // WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Height := 97;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.AutoSize := True;

  // now you got some space on the welcome page, so let's fill it up with
  // your own label called WelcomeLabel3
  WelcomeLabel3 := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  WelcomeLabel3.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
  WelcomeLabel3.AutoSize := False;
  WelcomeLabel3.Left := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Left;
  WelcomeLabel3.Top := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Top +
    WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Height;
  WelcomeLabel3.Width := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Width;
  WelcomeLabel3.Height := WizardForm.WelcomePage.Height - WelcomeLabel3.Top;
  WelcomeLabel3.Font.Assign(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font);
  WelcomeLabel3.Caption := CustomMessage('WelcomeLabel3');

  // these three lines can help you to see the label composition since it
  // colorize them; remove this when you'll be done
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Color := clYellow;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Color := $000080FF;
  WelcomeLabel3.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Comment: your help is greatly appreciated, perfect solution and clearly explained..Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply change the `ClickNext` message as follows:

```
[Messages]
ClickNext=Click Next to continue, or Cancel to exit Setup.%n%nADD YOUR TEXT HERE
```

Comment: The only problem I can see is that you'll have to override messages for all languages that you use. P.S. please do not use answers for contacting someone (the users are not notified anyway). That's what comments are for.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, this is also a good option, but only if no formatting need to be done in newly added text.In case of formatting like making text bold or coloring we have to use [CustomMessages] as mentioned in previous answer.